# Adding a new action into resource controller routes form handling

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am opening a form inside one of the pages generated by JeffreyWay's laravel generator.
Except it keeps saying unknown action even though i added the action in the WorkorderController. If I change it to the default actions that was created it worked fine.. like action => 'WorkordersController@create'

Does anyone know how to register a new action using the Route::Resource?

Thanks!

in my form

```
 {{ Form::open(array('action' => 'WorkordersController@time')) }}
```

in my WorkorderController

```
public function time()
    {

        return 'hello world';
    }
```

in my routes

```
Route::resource('workorders', 'WorkordersController');
```

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way to resolve this is creating a separate route to your action:

```
Route::resource('workorders', 'WorkordersController');
Route::post('workorders/time', array('as'=>'workorders.time', 'uses'=>'WorkordersController@time'));
```

But you also can extend the whole Laravel router system and add new actions.

Comment: I had to put `Route::resource` after all the other ones (e.g. `Route::post`) in order to make it work.

Comment: Bartek is right, the docs say "you should define those routes before your call to Route::resource" - see: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers